# How to correct fragment not launching issue?

Tags: android, android-fragments

i am launching a activity hosting a fragment with a list of items..

When an item is clicked. The layout is tested for threePane or not.

```
    public void onFeedSelected(Feed feed) {
    if (isThreePane) {
        addItemsFragment(feed);
    }
    else {
        Intent i=new Intent(this, ItemsActivity.class);

        i.putExtra(ItemsActivity.EXTRA_FEED_KEY, feed.getKey());

        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

As you can see if it is not three pane then it launches an activity..This works fine on regular phones.

But if it is a tablet screen the activity isnt launched in the fragment.

Here is my AddFeed() method.

```
public void addItemsFragment(Feed feed) {
    FragmentManager fragMgr=getSupportFragmentManager();
    ItemsFragment items=(ItemsFragment)fragMgr.findFragmentById(R.id.second_pane);
    FragmentTransaction xaction=fragMgr.beginTransaction();

    if (items==null) {
        items=new ItemsFragment(true);
        items.setOnItemListener(this);

        xaction
            .add(R.id.second_pane, items)
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
    }
    else {
        ContentFragment content=
            (ContentFragment)fragMgr.findFragmentById(R.id.third_pane);

        if (content!=null) {
            xaction.remove(content).commit();
            fragMgr.popBackStack();
        }
    }
```

I dont understand why its not being launched..When i click the item it does nothing on a tablet device.

EDIT:

```
private boolean isThreePane=false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    FeedsFragment feeds
        =(FeedsFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
                                                    .findFragmentById(R.id.feeds);

    feeds.setOnFeedListener(this);

    isThreePane=(null!=findViewById(R.id.second_pane));

    if (isThreePane) {
        feeds.enablePersistentSelection();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the isThreePane variable? And where does it get set to true or false? can you post all of the code where this variable is changed? My guess is that isThreePane is getting set to true on the tablet for some reason. You might try putting a log message in the if and else and see which one is actually happening.

Comment: Check out my edit. Just posted the code

Comment: What tablet are you using? Is it honeycomb or not?

Comment: Its honeycomb. Acer iconia a500

Comment: I just debugged and isThreePane is returning true on my tab

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the Fragment API at all so this is total shot in the dark...

```
isThreePane=(null!=findViewById(R.id.second_pane));
```

is getting set to true on the tablet, so that means `findViewById(R.id.second_pane)` is not returning null. Do you have this second_pane view hard coded in your xml? How does the app decide whether or not the second_pane view should be present? Is it based on screen size at all?

Should you be using something like this:

```
fragMgr.findFragmentById(R.id.second_pane);
```

Instead of findViewById? Again I know nothing about fragments api, sorry if that is silly question.

Comment: Android can load different XML layouts depending on the device that loads the app. By checking if the view exists, you can find out which layout was loaded (ie: two_pane view exists = large display device)

Comment: So is two_pane supposed to exist for large devices but not medium/small devices? If that view is your layout.xml that is inside layout-large then it is definitely going to exist if you are using a large screen device.

Comment: Your right spidy. Thats how it knows if threePane is true or not.